# Display: flex - Two elements into 500px horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, flexbox

I am trying to align 2 horizontal divs. But for some reason the second div is outside of #content.

- #content: width: 500px;
- #flex_container: Display: flex;
- #main: 100%
- Table: 100%
- #sidebar 250px;

I need two cases:

**First**) Only green table 100% (not outside of #content) - sidebar not exist

**Second**) Two div: table and sidebar horizontally into 500px (not outside of #content)

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/69hd4ov1/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="flex_container">
        <div id="main">
           <table class="table"></table>
           <div id="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an image of your intended layout?
Your code snippet in Stackoverflow has the #sidebar inside the #main div, while your jsfiddle does not. Which is it?

Comment: @FeKuLa are your problem solve ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want the green div(siderbar) on the right of the table.
Since you declare the wrapper div(main div) 500px then and the table to 100% then the table will have 500px and the second div(sidebar) will overlap on the table because there is no space available.
If you want a fix width then you must assign wrapper div(content) 750px and then the table 500px and sidebar 250px.
If you want to be responsive(base on the screen dimension) you can set also 500px wrapper(or 100% having the full page width) div and for the table 70% and sidebar 30% or whatever percentage you want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 500px;
    background: Red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100vh;
}
#content #flex_container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
  
}
table{
 table-layout: fixed;


}
#content #main {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
     flex:1;
      overflow-x:auto;
}
#sidebar {
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
    background: yellow;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="flex_container">
        <div id="main">
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
          <th scope="col">Header</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
          <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
        <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're set the `width` of `#content` to `500px` and you set the `width` of `#main` to `100%` means that it will take all width of its parent which is `500px` and the overflowing `#sidebar` have a half of its container(`250px`) so that it make sense to overflow what you can do you can set the `width` of `#content` to `50%` and the `#sidebar` to `50%` but the content inside the `#sidebar` will overflow so increase the `width` of `#content` like the following

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 700px;
  background: Red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content #flex_container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#content #main {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="flex_container">
    <div id="main">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
            <th scope="col">Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```